# Am I authenticating devices securely?

Tags: authentication, hmac, iot

I'm building a IOT platform for my home as a hobby. Currently, I'm trying to implement device authentication. A device in my case could be a Raspberry Pi, Arduino, Jetson Nano. To authenticate devices I want to use HMAC.

A device is assigned a shared key, which is saved in a database and on the device.
The device calculates a HMAC signature using the shared key. The payload would look like this:

```
"HMAC-SHA256" +\n +
Created-at timestamp + \n +
device id + / + device topic
```

<s>Since this is happening on an embedded system with limited resources I cannot expect to use TLS. Therefore, I'll encrypt the signature and the payload using AES.</s> As was pointed out in the comments, TLS is possible on embedded systems. No need for AES.

POST the signature and payload to a REST endpoint. The endpoint calculates the signature. If the two signatures match, the device is authenticated. Hurray!

Is this a good and secure way to implement authentication? Is there a better, less convoluted way to accomplish this? Maybe I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be.

How should I store the shared keys in the database? To calculate the signature it needs to be readable.

Comment: Check out more recent developments: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4/how-to-get-https-on-arduino

Comment: Thank you! This simplifies things a bit.

Comment: There are TLS libraries for Arduino. As you control the environment you can limit the supported TLS version and cipher to those that work best with the embedded device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some discussion of TLS vs AES but I'll start from the post as originally written.

There's nothing obscenely wrong with the system as presented.  The only issue immediately apparent would be a replay attack, where an attacker would capture an update and try to reuse it later.  The timestamp would need to be accurate and updates only accepted within a narrow window of time.  Also out of order updates discarded (updates older than the latest update).  Slightly better would be going to the server for a session-key and including that in a message (expiration after x second of not being used, only issuing a single session key per device at a time, etc, etc).

The corporate answer to how to store symmetric keys is a Key Management System (KMS) (all cloud providers have one).  For something a bit more homebrew, best practice would be a database which is encrypted at rest.  If there's any money at play, use a KMS.

TLS with mutual authentication would get around these concerns.  Replay is prevented by the Diffie-Hellman key exchange and the only key material that needs to be tracked is Certificate Authority key material and any revoked key material which has not yet expired.  Best practice is offline root and an intermediate to sign devices/server's public keys but small operations could get away with less.  It just really sucks to have to revoke one's root key.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

For anyone intersted, I chose the mutual TLS route that foreverska suggested. Basically, I didn't change much in my app, but I did add nginx and I'm using it as a reverse proxy, for TLS termination and for client certificate verification.

What is left for me to do is add the device certificate signing and certificate revocation functionality.

---

I've decided to enforce TLS on all my devices. This is probably the most sensible way. When choosing devices, I'll have to pick one that supports it. However, TLS only authenticates the server.

To authenticate the devices I think I'll still choose HMAC. For example, every time a device publishes a message it sends the computed HMAC signature of the message body along with it. The recipient verifies the authenticity of that message by computing and comparing signatures.

Comment: It's good that you're on the TLS bandwagon.  But to clarify, TLS can be configured as "Mututal TLS" which authenticates both the client and the server.  This comes at the added cost of key management for embedded devices but it is available.  Source:  Just did an integration of mbed TLS 1.2 with mututal authentication.

Comment: @foreverska Thanks. I'll have to read up on mutual TLS. How would you keep track of the issued client keys and how would you revoke a key?

Comment: So in the perfect scenario you have a root CA and an intermediate CA.  The intermediate CA signs any devices or servers.  Root stays offline and only signs intermediates.  Upon connection they both present each other with their public cert and any signing certs leading back to a root CA they both might agree on.  This way you don't need to track devices, just intermediates.  If your intermediate is safe, anything signed by it is presumed to be good.  Revocation is a much bigger topic.  I'd suggest googling CRLset, mbedtls has provisions for it.  That's all I can authoritatively say.

Comment: I think I bit off more than I can chew... But it's a good learning experience. I'll update this post with my progress. :)

Comment: Somehow I missed the hobby portion of the original post, so I was giving a very corporate answer.  I'll write something more nuanced in a real answer.